# send xml to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

Can someone provide an example of how to send an xml from C# to SQL Server, and then loop on the xml in the stored procedure that got it, and update or enter line by line.

Comment: What version of SqlServer? The newer versions have an 'xml' datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the three-part series on SQL XML on 15seconds: http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/050803.htm.

I would personally use the SQL XQuery functions to shred apart your XML into bits and pieces and store those in SQL Server.

If you have something like:

```
<data>
  <person>
     <name>Jones</name>         
     <firstname>Peter</firstname>
  </person>
  <person>
     <name>Smith</name>         
     <firstname>Frank</firstname>
  </person>
<data>
```

you can write something like:

```
SELECT
   Data.Person.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as 'Name',
   Data.Person.value('(firstname)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as 'First Name'
FROM 
   @XmlVar.nodes('/data/person') As Data(Person)
```

So basically, the `.nodes` function shreds your XML into a "pseudo-table" `Data.Person` - each `<person>` entry becomes one row in the table.

With the `.value()` function, you can extract single values from those shredded XML nodes. You now have a bunch of varchar(20) fields, that can be e.g. inserted into a table.

This method works well if your XML is fairly small (a few hundred entries). If you have huge XML files, you might want to investigate other methods, such as [XML Bulkload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Comment: Sound like what I'm looking for. TY

Answer (score -1):

I am making a lot of assumptions as your question is not clear.

What you could do is create a stored procedure in SQL Server that accept a string as parameter. This string should contain the Xml that you want to process. See the following snippet for a possible stored procedure that processes the XML.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_ProcessXml]
(
  @data AS NTEXT
) 
AS
/* Create a temporary table to insert the Xml data*/         
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL )
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#temp] 
( 
  /* your table definition */
)

DECLARE @handle AS INTEGER
DECLARE @flags  AS INTEGER 

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @data

/* Supported is only element mapping */ 
SET @flags = 2

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#temp] 
  SELECT [Insert xml fields] 
  FROM OPENXML (@handle, '[Xpath in XmlDocument', @flags)
  WITH (Id  INTEGER)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle  

/* Select data from Xml and from several normal tables if needed */
SELECT  [Insert your Fields]
  FROM dbo.[#temp] t 

 DROP TABLE [dbo].[#temp]  

RETURN
```

Comment: Wow...New code for me. Can you explain what's going on here? TY.