# Repeater Loses it's data on PostBacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Repeater Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="stat_Rptr" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="IsSelected_ChkBx" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Item") %>' />
                    &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="Value_TxtBx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="ID_HdnFld" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <SeparatorTemplate>
                    <br></br>
                </SeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Code-Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateStatRptr();
        }
     }


    private void PopulateStatRptr()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        string _connString = "Data Source=localhost\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True";

        conn = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Item FROM Stats", conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            stat_Rptr.DataSource = reader;
            stat_Rptr.DataBind();
            reader.Close();
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting separator choice.  Why not just `<br/>`?

Comment: Believe me, this is not visually comforting.

Comment: Just in the development stage, it is for me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, it seems that  Repeater is a dynamic control.  If you are binding in the codebehind  you have to realize that the textbox and checkboxes in the itemtemplate do not exist until you DataBind(). If you disable viewstate, you won't see them unless you databind on every page load. You are getting your values from viewstate in this case.

Check this [link](http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/repeaters-and-lost-data-after-postback-viewstate/) out.

Comment: Thanks, that worked and the repeater control and the data are persistent .. although this means that the data will bind each time a PostBack happens!

Comment: It is totally ok to bind data on every postback. You should disable viewstate unless you really really need it. Usually there are several controls on the page that don't need viewstate but creates overhead. A single database call is sometimes better than having the viewsate on, depending on the page and the database call performance.

Comment: Actually this page's function is to create an item .. this item has many properties and each set of properties are under a category (I put them in Divs) and I use buttons to display those divs .. so I might need to go to the first div, then go to the third one and come back to the first to edit or add something and finally save .. so I think ViewState is essential here .. and database calls are a lot too because I need to retrieve all the data in the controls and save them to multiple tables in my Db

Comment: Viewstate has nothing to do with anything unless you post the data back. Moving around in the page (until you finally click save), does not affect viewstate. I'm not sure of your exact requirements, but you should probably create an object (depending on whether it makes sense as a business object) to hold the entire item and send it to database as serialized xml. On how to process xml in sql, here is a link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756773/c-send-xml-to-sql

Comment: Here's an example:
Div1: Personal Info
Div2: Skils
N.B I Navigate through the 2 divs through 2 buttons that shows the one that I need and hides the other divs.

Now both divs contain controls to enter some related data, I might just enter my name in the first divs and then go to the second divs add a skill, and I need to go back to the first divs to continue my personal info .. this switching will happen a lot, so I need to keep the info persistent in the controls so If I switch from a div to another I don't want to lose the data that I entered first. I hope you got the requirements :)

Comment: can you use the asp.net wizard control? Otherwise, perhaps you can get the data once, and store it in the session? it is better to avoid repeater control, use gridview or listview or something like that.

Comment: I'm sorry but sometimes things you know suddenly becomes wrong! .. I've been developing ASP.NET for more than a year on and off .. and I've always used a repeater and avoided GridView and DetailsView in all the books they said this controls come with a lot of great and easy to use options but it's better not to use them .. and read hundreds of tutorials to build paging, filtering, etc using a repeater as it's the most simple and non-performance degrading control ..I'm sorry! do you have any books, articles, anything because I feel like I'm lost on what controls should I use now =S

Comment: I did not mean to say that. Repeater does give you better performance, but it also comes with some headaches that you need to be very careful with. What I would like you to do is to ask another question on this regard to hear from the other experts. Hear from other people who have used repeater extensively or not. and then make a decision. Its better to avoid a chat like discussion in comments on SO.

Comment: Yeah I know but as you see, I put a comment and reply later. a chat wouldn't be my best option. but thanks for replying and for me headaches are better than degrading my application performance. and If I asked this question I'll sure let you know =). +1

Answer (score 5):

Bind on Page_Init instead of Page_Load.

Comment: I'm sorry how do I create a Page_Init handler ?

Comment: protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: I used the article in coder net's answer (OnInit) and used yours and both works perfectly good but I don't know if there's any difference! ..+1 Thank you and if you have any further clarification It would be good :)

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `if (!IsPostBack)` code and call your function every time.

Comment: Ok, This will solve the problem but I don't think it's good to Bind every PostBack, Plus I'm binding 4 CheckBoxLists in the very same way and I call them from Page_Load in the same if(!IsPostBack) condition and it works fine! .. it's very weird

Comment: @IKashef - Actually, it usually is a good idea to bind on every postback. We normally think of database queries as expensive for performance (and they are), but you know what's even more expensive? Uploading a large viewstate from halfway across the country. Even fast broadband connections often have relatively slow upstream speeds, and the extra latency can make your page _seem_ slower even if the actual render time is lightning fast. The exception, of course, if this is an intranet page for the local LAN only.

Comment: Your comment makes sense +1 .. but the problem is that I just get the values for the CheckBox.Text, HiddenField.Value .. but when I click my save button I need to retrieve the TextBox.Text and the CheckBox.Checked values and store them in my database .. in this way my repeater resets everything so the new entered data in my controls will be lost anyway!

Comment: @Joel it is easy to keep ViewState on the server so this is not really relevant to the issue. The result of the database query can be cached or stored in session in order to enable databinding on every Page_Load.

Comment: @Peter .. Sorry I Lost you! .. could you rephrase what should be done or how things go for the databinding with a database thing ?

Comment: Joel - I've found that if you call Page.DataBind() every time though, that you can lose postback values? I've had a bunch of <input type="text"> items, and if I trigger a button postback then their values seem to get overwritten with the original value if I always databind. Yet a repeater seems to require it.

Comment: This would cause `Invalid postback or callback argument` exception