# User Control inside Repeater - Values lost on PostBack - RadRating

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, telerik, postback, repeater

I have a UserControl Inside a repeater, coded in the following way:

ParentPage.aspx:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

    <uc1:MovieDetailPanel runat="server" myMovieID='<%# Eval("movieID") %>' myMovieName='<%# Eval("movieName") %>' 
            myMovieDescription='<%#Eval("movieDescription") %>' myMovieImagePath='<%# Eval("posterImage") %>'
        myMovieYear ='<%# Eval("movieYear") %>' myMovieGenre ='<%# Eval("movieGenre") %>' myMovieAverageRating ='<%# Eval("movieRating") %>'
        myMovieCountry ='<%# Eval("movieCountry") %>' myMovieLanguage ='<%# Eval("movieLanguage") %>'
            id="MovieDetailPanel1" />

    </ContentTemplate>

    </ItemTemplate>


    </asp:Repeater>
```

ParentPage.cs:

```
    private void LoadMyControls()
    { 
        Repeater1.DataSource = new Common().getMoviesList(selectedGenre, selectedYear, selectedPopularity, selectedLanguage, selectedCountry);
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
```

UserControl.cs:

```
public int myMovieID { get; set; }

    public string myMovieName { get; set; }

    public double myMovieAverageRating { get; set; }

    //some more properties
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MovieRatingControl.Value = myMovieAverageRating ;
        } 
    }
```

I have a `Telerik RadRating (ID# MovieRatingControl)` in my UserControl. On page load of the UserControl I am setting the value of the rating control, as passed by repeater from Database (wrapped it inside if(!Page.IsPostBack) as shown above. So each movie gets its own rating as present in the database.

However, on postback (when I click the rate button), the `RadRating` Control loses its value and becomes 0. This happens on all the UserControls inside the repeater and not just the UserControl in which I clicked the Rate button. Can someone please let me know how I am supposed to retain this rating value ? I need to get that and update my DB Tables.

P.S: If im not using if `(!Page.IsPostBack)`, I retain values from DB but not the rating set by the user. The issue is, the rating set by user is not maintained.

Comment: Where is `LoadMyControls` called? On initial load? On postback? My guess would be (unfortunately there's not enough code to be sure) that your control is re-populating the data before you are processing any potentially updated details (e.g. the rating) which would cause it to be overwritten. (PS: Your code needs updating as it doesn't appear to be quite right, e.g. the repeater is incomplete)

Comment: You might also find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886683/repeater-loses-its-data-on-postbacks

Comment: You can also try late events in the US lifecycle like PreRender if you store data in the ViewState, to ensure it is already loaded. You can also try removing the postback check. With dynamic controls - make sure they all have IDs and they don't change across postbacks.

Comment: Do you use LoadControls() somewhere? I am not sure, but probably this will lead to not having the controls in the ViewState.